# Atomic Transaction in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, transactions, atomic

In traditional Sql databases, transactions work like this:

```
transaction start

sql query 1 in Table A

sql query 2 in Table B

sql query 3 in Table C

transaction end

commit
```

Is that how transactions in MongoDB work? If so, what are the steps? If not, how should I manipulate multiple collections with multiple queries with Atomicity.